# File_get_contents и https

Tags: php

Вылезает вот такая ошибка

Warning: file_get_contents(https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&scope=offline,friends&client_id=#&client_secret=#&username=gf&password=fg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in /var/www/vh38503/data/www/l.su/api/er.php on line 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file_get_contents работает если это разрешают на сервере куда вы ломитесь.

для подобных целей используйте библиотеку cURL